# Date doesn't appear correctly using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, date

I am using AngularJS with ASP.Net MVC to show the user's data. 
When the MVC view start, it calls Angular module to fetch the data from database:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
        <td>{{p.UserName}}</td>
        <td>{{p.UserDoB}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteProduct(p)">X</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In Angular controller, I just sent ajax request to MVC action method:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetUser')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.users= result;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

In the GetUser method, again it is normal method to read from the database:

```
public JsonResult GetUser()
    {
        User userData = (User)Session["user"];            
        var db = new scaleDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          join uc in db.UserContacts
                          on userObj.Id equals uc.usrID
                          join us in db.Users
                          on userObj.usrSupervisor equals us.Id
                          where userObj.Id.Equals(userData.Id)
                          select new
                          {
                              usrNme = userObj.usrNme,
                              usrdob = userObj.usrDoB,                                  
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
    }
```

If you can see, the usrDoB is a SQL Server database field and its datatype is Date. 
My problem is, the date value is correct when I open the table using SQL Server Management Studio, but it is not correct on the application using Angular.

For example, the date `12/28/1979` appears like this: `/Date(315187200000)/`??

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Sorry I have mistake in the code above. On the HTML code block, ignore the word **products** because it is actually **users**

Comment: But I hope that you've got the idea

Comment: Issue has nothing to do with angular and everything to do with a misconfigured Newtonsoft Json.net.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with :

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);  
ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
```

With that, i change dynamically the data format during the binding.

See full solution in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/Mp7kT/) and for reference how $parsers and $formatters are used took a look on [Parser and Formatters](https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html)

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net MVC controllers are not using Newtonsoft Json.net for building JsonResult, but use JavaScriptSerializer. That's why the date is not formatted properly.

The easiest solution would be move your action to Web Api controller (`ApiController`), so Newtonsoft Json.net will be used.

Another option is to create custom `ActionResult`. See example [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));` to convert the JSON date to the correct format inside javascript.Here's a complete example:

**Controller:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AngularDates()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetDates()
    {
        var e1 = new Employee { ID = 0, DOB = new DateTime(1988, 10, 27) };
        var e2 = new Employee { ID = 1, DOB = new DateTime(1969, 05, 09) };
        var employees = new List<Employee> { e1, e2 };

        return Json(new { Employees = employees }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.module("app").controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

        $scope.GetDates = function (employee) {

            $http.get("/Home/GetDates").
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                debugger;
                data = data.Employees;

                for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
                {
                    var employee = data[i];
                    var date = employee.DOB;
                    var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));

                    var message = "Before - " + date + ". After - " + formattedDate;
                    alert(message);

                    data[i].DOB = formattedDate;
                }

                $scope.employees = data;


            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
        }
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div id="mainController" ng-controller="mainController">
        <input type="button" ng-click="GetDates()" value="Get Dates" />
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat="e in employees">
                <td>{{e.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{e.DOB | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteProduct(p)">X</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output in the browser:**

[image: Displaying JSON dates in AngularJS]